# Paypal IPN check fails on Pantheon

Tags: paypal, pantheon, ipn

I recently moved our site to the Pantheon platform. The domain is the same (except the 'www' is now default where previously non-www was the default).

But we have just received this email from Paypal:

> Dear so-and-so,
>
> Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment
>   Notifications (IPN). Instant Payment Notifications sent to the
>   following URL(s) are failing:
>
> http://www.mysite.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/ipn.php?r
>   eset=1&contactID=1495&contributionID=1047&module=contribute&membershipID=627
>
> If you do not recognize this URL, you may be using a service provider
>   that is using IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider
>   with the above information. **If this problem continues, IPNs may be
>   disabled for your account.**
>
> Thank you for your prompt attention to this issue.

I tried accessing the address and got there without any trouble. Why might this be happening and how could it be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

I have been directed to this patch:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2177647

I can't tell you whether it works or not yet since it will take a few weeks to be sure. But it seems to be the going solution.

Comment: Testing PayPal IPN via their test console, I was able to make IPNs to non-Pantheon sites, but not to a Pantheon site.

Comment: **Pantheon > (your site) > Live > Errors** says "session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: )sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/ipn.php:34" which matches what's reported in [#2177647: on Pantheon: php error: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2177647).

Comment: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17212